# KeyError while using drop in python data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe like:
[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icZ9q.png)

I am using the code: `df.drop(df[len(df['subjects'].str.split())<3].index,inplace=True)`
to drop all the rows which has less than 3 subjects. But on executing this code I am getting an error:
`raise KeyError(key) from err` What could be the reason for this?

I tried using the drop function by providing the appropriate condition, but it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is `len(df['subjects'].str.split())<3` is not returning what you expect, its simply checking the length (number of rows) in your dataframe is less than three and returning False.   And, False is not a dataframe index, value, thus the KeyError.

You can do it like this using boolean indexing:

```
df[~(df['subjects'].str.split(' ').str.len()<3)]
```

Output:

```
  school_id state_code                   subjects
0     sch_1      !@sc1   english maths chemistray
1     sch_2     ))sc_2  english physics chemistry
```